# Code execution throws error "object is not a function"

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When i execute the below code i get the below error.
uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

```
    <html>
    <script>
    var obj_1 = {x:1, y:2}
    (function (o)
    {
        for(i in o)
        {
        console.log(i);
        }
    })(obj_1);

    </script>
    </html>
```

Please explain what causes this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a semi-colon after your declaration. It thinks you're trying to call `{x:1, y:2}()`. Semi colons are optional and usually work, unless you have something ambiguous as you do.

That is why you should always use semi-colons;

Another thing you should always do is not create global variables as you are in your `for` loop

```
// This works
var obj_1 = {x:1, y:2};
(function (o)
{
    for(var i in o)
    {
    console.log(i);
    }
})(obj_1);
```

When you don't finish a line with `;`, JavaScript will first try to incorporate the next line into the statement, if it can't, then it acts as if there were a `;`.

```
// The following inserts a semi-colon because
// "var x = 2 x = 3" is not a valid statement
var x = 2
var x = 3

// The following does not insert a semi-colon because
// "var x = $().height(50).width(100);" is a valid statement
var x = $('p').
       height(50).
       width(100);
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, would you please explain why this error occurs in general?

Comment: @user2713706 Which part is not clear? Because you don't have a semi colon, the JavaScript engine tried to make a function call out of your `()` that follows the object declaration `{x:1, y:2}`